# Transform fte table into mulptiple lines

Tags: sql, sql-server

The first table shows data of employee which is changing FTE during the year. Based on that I would like to adjust second table (show absences).

I need to show FTE for the absence in which occurred. For example first row (from the second table) it happened `2016-05-09` - `2016-05-09` so it is easy FTE will be `0.74`.

The issue happened with second row (in absence table) where absence happened during 3 different FTE changes from the first table (shown in the image below)

Could you help me with such update? My expected result is in the 3rd table.

[image]

Comment: What happens on the edge cases?  So if the absence date fall on, say 2016-04-04, which FTE values is selected?

Comment: Good point. Thanks. I think should take it higer date. So in your example FTE should be 0.74

Comment: And then there are the dates that cross boundaries... how should an absence between 2016-04-02 and 2016-04-07 be handled.   I think you need to consider all the requirements and possible condition before embarking on writing the sql.

Answer (score 0):

This will fulfill the results in your example

```
    update a
    set a.type=FTE.FTE
    from Absense a
    inner join FTE on a.Start_date>=fte.Start_date and a.EndDate<=fte.End_Date
    where FTE.type is null
```

**BUT** the requirements need to be defined more precisely because there are complications when handling date ranges that enclose multiple FTE date ranges.  Once the 'rules' for the edge cases for dates and cross-bounadaries are clearly defined, the correct query could be more complex than this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did something like

Comment: SELECT a.[ID]
 , CASE WHEN a.[Start_date] >= f.[Start_date] THEN a.[Start_date] ELSE f.[Start_date] END AS [Start_date]
 , CASE WHEN a.[End_date] <= f.[End_date] THEN a.[End_date] ELSE f.[End_date] END AS [End_date]
 , a.[type]
 , f.[FTE]
FROM Absence_table a
LEFT JOIN FTE_table f ON a.[ID] = f.[ID]
    AND a.[Start_date] < f.[End_date]
    AND a.[End_date] >= f.[Start_date]